# How to develop Sharepoint Online Add-ins on MacOS?

Tags: macos, angular, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm currently doing some research on how to develop Sharepoint Online Add-ins. In various documentations Microsoft refers to Visual Studio with the office development suite. I downloaded Visual Studio for Mac but can't seem to get the office dev tools.

Also, i found the various documentations a bit hard and confusing. As someone with no Sharepoint experience I was wondering if it is possible to convert a small Angular 4 "app" to a Sharepoint Add-In.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no SharePoint add-in SDK for macOS. As a result, we can't develop SharePoint Add-in on macOS. If we want to do some SharePoint development on macOS, we may consider to use SharePoint framework to develop SharePoint web parts and extensions.

Yes, it is possible to convert Angular app to SharePoint add-in, however, SharePoint add-in is an iframe on SharePoint page. Some feature of the app, such as responsiveness is limited in the add-in.